# Programmatically creating .desktop file to autostart application

Tags: linux, gnome, java, startup, desktop-file

Using a Java program, I added a `.desktop` file in `/etc/xdg/autostart` to run a script when a user logs in. The script didn't run at user login, and when I checked the start up applications dialog manually, it wasn't added to it.

The file I added is `/etc/xdg/autostart/Startup.desktop`, and the script I want to be run on user login is `/usr/bin/Startscript`. The code I wrote to add the desktop file is as follows:

```java
private void writeDesktopFile() {

        File f = new File("/etc/xdg/autostart/Startup.desktop");
        if (!(f.exists())) {
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f, true));
                bw.write("[Desktop Entry]");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.append("Name=Startup");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.append("Exec=Startscript");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.append("Type=Application");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.append("Terminal=false");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.append("Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.append("X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=Startscript");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
                bw.close();
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod +x /usr/bin/Startscript");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LinuxStartup.class.getName())
                        .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

Why isn't my script being run on start up?

Comment: Is there another `Startup.desktop` in another autostart directory, such as `$HOME/.config/autostart/`? What are the actual contents of `/etc/xdg/autostart/Startup.desktop` after running your program?

Comment: @DanGetz Yes there was another script in `/.config/autostart`. I removed it and tried but same result. What causes the script to automatically insert in `/.config/autostart` folder?

Comment: Was that file exactly equal to the one you had created in `/etc/xdg/autostart/`? Or was it a different file? Once again, it's important to check the contents of these `.desktop` files.